# Stripping Pandas DataFrame on specific conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SP':[35.6,56.7,np.nan,-9.2],'1M':[-7.8,np.nan,56,-3.4],'3M':[24,-31,53,np.nan]}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','SP','1M','3M'])
print df
```

I would like to run a test on certain columns in this DataFrame only, all column names in this list:

```
check = {'1M','SP'}
print check
```

I would like a stripped down version of my DataFrame df such as it contains only the column Series_Date where values in columns that are in the list, 'check' are either NaNs or negative.

In this case, the output df will thus have all Series_Date where value in either 1M or SP column is negative or a NaN.

Could you please help how I could get around with something like this? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use smart indexing:

```
import numpy as np
# Choose the columns of interest
cols = df[list(check)]
# Evaluate both conditions:
cond = ((np.isnan(cols)) | (cols < 0))
# Use boolean indexing to select the right rows
df[cond.any(axis=1)]['Series_Date']    
#0    2017-03-10
#1    2017-03-13
#2    2017-03-14
#3    2017-03-15
#Name: Series_Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: I want the Series Date column where values in SP and 1M columns are either NaN or negative. This answer just returns the entire DF

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the second part of your question. See the updated answer. By the way, in your example the whole DF is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [18]: df.loc[df.loc[:, check].fillna(-1).lt(0).any(1), 'Series_Date']
Out[18]:
0    2017-03-10
1    2017-03-13
2    2017-03-14
3    2017-03-15
Name: Series_Date, dtype: object
```

**OLD answer:**

```
In [7]: df.loc[:, check]
Out[7]:
     SP    1M
0  35.6  -7.8
1  56.7   NaN
2   NaN  56.0
3  -9.2  -3.4
```

or you can use `df.columns.isin()` method

```
In [6]: df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(check)]
Out[6]:
     SP    1M
0  35.6  -7.8
1  56.7   NaN
2   NaN  56.0
3  -9.2  -3.4
```

Comment: I want the Series Date column where values in SP and 1M columns are either NaN or negative. This answer just returns the entire DF.